# How create angular 2 selector in runtime?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the next component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'todo',
    templateUrl: 'app/todo/todo.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/todo/todo.component.css']
})
export class Todo implements OnInit{
    placeHolder: string = "Please enter a TODO task";
    taskValue: string = "";

    ngOnInit(): void { 

    };
}
```

And i have also this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-panel',
    templateUrl: 'app/main-panel/main-panel.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/main-panel/main-panel.component.css']
})
export class MainPanel implements OnInit{
    panelTitle: string = 'Welcome to ODOT';
    sTodo: string = 'TODO';
    sDoing: string = 'Doing';
    sDone: string = 'Done';
    userName: string = 'User name';
    password: string = 'Password';
    signUp: string = 'Sign up';
    signIn: string = 'Sign in';

    addTodoTask(): void {
      console.log("Hi");  
    };

    ngOnInit(): void {       
    };
}
```

I want that every time addTodoTask event triggered I will add new **todo** selector with all its properties and methods to the main-panel.HTML, any ideas?

Thanks,

Shay Zambrovski

Comment: are you talking about dynamically loading a component on your page?

Comment: @amansoni211 I think so...

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/831/dynamically-add-components-using-viewcontainerref-createcomponent/28405/dynamically-add-component-on-specific-eventclick#t=201703010845477112628

Answer (score 0):

```
items = [];
addTodoTask(): void {
  this.items.push(this.items.length);
}
```

```
<todo *ngFor="let item of items">
<button (click)="addTodoTask()">add</button>
```

Comment: what is the connection between items and Todo component?